# Encapsulation C# Best practices

Tags: c#, encapsulation

just for clarification and for good code practices. I understand the concept of encapsulation, but can you tell me the difference between these two codes and in which scenario would you use them. Thanks. PS: I am not looking for links answers, I just want your honest opinion.

Code 1:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car ObjCar = new Car();
        printVehicledetails(ObjCar);
    }

    private static void printVehicledetails(Vehilce vehicle) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here are the Vehicles' details: {0}", vehicle.FormatMe());
    }
}

abstract class Vehilce
{
    protected string Make { get; set; } //here
    protected string Model { get; set; } //here

    public abstract string FormatMe();

}

class Car : Vehilce
{

    public override string FormatMe()
    {

        return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Make, Model);
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car ObjCar = new Car();
        printVehicledetails(ObjCar);
    }

    private static void printVehicledetails(Vehilce vehicle) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here are the Vehicles' details: {0}", vehicle.FormatMe());
    }
}

abstract class Vehilce
{
    public string Make { protected get; protected set; } //here
    public string Model { protected get; protected set; } //here

    public abstract string FormatMe();

}

class Car : Vehilce
{

    public override string FormatMe()
    {

        return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Make, Model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, do you want the `Make` and `Model` to be changed by code external to the type or derived types?

Comment: These two pieces of code do different things. Also the second one makes no sense since there is no way provided to actually set `Make` or `Model`. Even with valid code (eg addition of constructor taking values for these) I think the question is too broad and subjective for a good answer.

Comment: This isn't an example of encapsulation. I can gain access to `Make` and `Model` by extending `Car`. They need to be private or internal to be encapsulated. Further, why create `FormatMe` and `printVehicledetails` at all? Just override `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common approach: separate data and logic. In that case you should make properties public (maybe with private setters) and put formatting somewhere else, for example, in extension method.

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on your context, wheather you need to access the properties from outside of any derived class or not. That´s the only difference on them, in last case you can access the properties only within `Vehicle`-class, wheras in the first you can access them from anywhere.

Btw.: Providing a access-modifier for both getter AND setter for a property will result in the following compile-time error.

> "Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property..."

The following works however:

```
protected string Make { get; set; } //here
```

Comment: In actual fact, the OP's code (`public string Model { protected get; protected set; }`) throws a compiler error: "Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property ..."

Comment: @MishaelOgochukwu Then feel free to upvote/accest answer